# Migrate h2 database to a postgresql docker in java spring

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, docker, h2

As titled, I am trying to migrate my h2 database to a postgres docker.

I made a dump of my h2 database using the command

```
SCRIPT TO 'fileName'
```

I then copied the file to my docker through the docker cp command. After that, I created a new database, and I tried launching

```
psql realdb < myfile.sql
```

which gave me an enourmous serie of errors, including:

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...TER TABLE PUBLIC.FILE_RECORD ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.CONSTRAIN...
                                                             ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CACHED"
LINE 1: CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.NODE_EVENT(
               ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...LTER TABLE PUBLIC.NODE_EVENT ADD CONSTRAINT PUBLIC.CONSTRAIN...
                                                             ^
ERROR:  relation "public.node_event" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO PUBLIC.NODE_EVENT(ID, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, MONTH, ...
                    ^
NOTICE:  table "system_lob_stream" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CALL"
LINE 1: CALL SYSTEM_COMBINE_BLOB(-1);
```

So I decided I would try dumping the database as a csv file, which perhaps a more standard approach, using the command

```
call CSVWRITE( '/home/lee/test.csv' , 'SELECT * FROM PORT' )
```

which seems to work for just one table at time. Is there a way to export all tables at once? How would I import them into postgres docker?

Is there a better way to do all of this?

This is my application.config

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:/tmp/ossdb:testdb;MODE=PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.platform=postgresql
```

Comment: Most likely there is no automated way. But if I were doing this I'd export it into `.sql` file just like you did and manually change table declarations to reflect postgresql syntax.